# VSCode Hotkey to show/hide all windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

iTerm2 has a very useful hotkey that allows me to show/hide all windows ([docs](https://iterm2.com/documentation-hotkey.html)). Does VSCode have a similar hotkey, or an easy way for me to configure it? It would greatly improve my productivity.

Comment: I think the OS itself has a shortcut to view all windows of an application (at least on my Mac it's ctrl + down arrow, I don't know about other OS's). Is the end goal to switch between different VS Code windows?

Comment: The goal is to open a vscode window from another app (e.g. Chrome) without having to use the mouse.